# react.development.js:220 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: reactjs

I have the following piece of code which is causing the following warning message

> react.development.js:220 Warning: Each child in a list should have a
> unique "key" prop.

```
          {data.map(item => (
            <tr>
              <td key={item.key}>{item.Number}</td>
              <td key={item.key}>{item.Name}</td>  
              <td key={item.key}>{item.LastName}</td>
              <td key={item.key}>{item.Reason}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
```

I have tried multiple different ways to get rid of the error to no avail. But still getting the following error. What can I do to get rid of the error?

EDIT:

I change it to the following and I no longer get the error.

```
          {data.map((item, i) => (
            <tr key={i}>
              <td>{item.Number}</td>
              <td>{item.Name}</td>  
              <td>{item.LastName}</td>
              <td>{item.Reason}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
```

Comment: The `key` prop is only required for the top element of your list, and in htis case that is your `tr` element (as a result of your `data.map((item) => (...)`

Comment: Did you try adding key to `tr` element?

Comment: Unfortunately it still occurs even though I have put it in the <tr> element

Comment: I edited the question with a working solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key prop needs to be added to the top level element in the list, so in this case the `tr` element. It should contain a value from the item being mapped that uniquely identifies the item, so if `item.key` is defined and is unique to that list item this should do the trick:

```
{data.map(item => (
   <tr key={item.key}>
     <td>{item.Number}</td>
     <td>{item.Name}</td>  
     <td>{item.LastName}</td>
     <td>{item.Reason}</td>
   </tr>
))}
```

Note, you should avoid using the index if possible as that may cause unexpected behaviour/performance problems. This is explained in the [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys)

Comment: Unfortunately it still occurs even though I have put it in the <tr> element

Comment: I edited the question with a working solution

Comment: @Arya There is nothing functionally different in your answer to mine, so long as `item.key` is identical for each item, except that yours (using the index) is definitely wrong and may cause unintended behaviour.

Comment: It looks like item.key is blank which is why I still get that error when using your answer.

Comment: Ok. I’ll edit my answer to make it clear what to do in this case shortly.